# Access BIOS-ROM in Assembly language (NASM)

Tags: assembly, nasm, bios

I am developing an experimental OS in Assembly language for educational purposes. Is it possible to read from the BIOS read-only memory and store it in any way, are there any interrupts for this? Is it protected?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in an operating system? Can you give more context for your question?

Comment: This will help you. I feel like I post this one every day. [Ralph Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm) :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to read ROM BIOS content - when your code is not under some protected mode OS like Linux or Windows - for example, when you are in the boot mode. At that time ROM BIOS content is in the memory at 0x000F0000 address - take a look at IBM PC system architecture [memory map](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)). So you can copy everything you need right from memory.

The next question is - how to save the data. You can save data to disk using BIOS [`int 13h` low-level disk access functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H). However, it is not very convenient as those functions are VERY low-level and work at disk data access level, not at file access level. So in order to write data to file you should write your own file working routines.

If you need ROM BIOS content only for study, you can use BIOS dump utilities - there are a lot of them.

Comment: I really don't like to see expressions like *x86 memory map* (not your invention, I know, so not your fault). That mixes system and CPU architecture terminology. The x86 CPUs don't have any requirement to have ROM at $F0000 - That is a convention imposed by the original *IBM PC system architecture*.

Comment: I agree, this layout reflects IBM PC architecture memory layout, not some specifics of x86 CPU architecture. Will fix it.